# backbone js getByCid not working

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

The backbone getByCid is not working when i viewed in console.log it showing the error as TypeError: test.getByCid is not a function. By using at(0).cid it shows the output as 'c1' why its not working.

```
var test=new Backbone.Collection([ 
   {name:'gowtham',age:10}
]);
console.log(test.at(0).cid); // output as c1
console.log(JSON.stringify(test.getByCid('c1'))); //TypeError: test.getByCid is not a function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `Backbone.Collection` does not have method `getByCid`, thats why you are getting this error.
But a collection has `get` method for getting a model.
it accepts one argument: `model` | `id` | `cid`

So if you want to get a model by cid, you can do it like this `collection.get(cidValue)`

```js
let collection = new Backbone.Collection();
let test1 = new Backbone.Model({ id: 1, value: 'first' });
let test2 = new Backbone.Model({ id: 2, value: 'second' });

collection.add([test1, test2]);

console.log(collection.get(2));
// find test2 by id

console.log(collection.get('c2'));
// find test2 by cid
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone.js"></script>
```